# PE file sections alignment

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, portable-executable

Why there is an alignment between section in PE file? Since the exact size of section can be specified in IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER.SizeOfRawData i don't see any sense of using these "gaps" between section.

In MSDN documentation for key /filealign there is written: "Valid values are 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, and 8192". Is there some reason why /filealign:0 is forbidden by compiler?

Comment: Somehow I think this is an artifact of optimization for much slower disks--like diskettes. 512 was a typical sector size. Seek and read would put the first byte of the particular section at the first byte of the buffer.

Comment: Well, I can actually compile my source with /filealign:[number lower than 512], but it always end up with error when I try to run that PE file.

Comment: I do feel this is an XY question. What are you actually looking to solve (or are you just curious)?

Comment: I'm just curious because if Windows loader is written correctly I can't see any sense of using file alignments.

Answer (score 2):

The following article from Matt Pietrek indicates that in RAM, a section must be aligned on a page boundary (which is 4096 bytes on x86 architecture). The section alignment does not have this constraint in the PE file so it can be shorter.

To check the page size of your architecture, the wikipedia article may be helpful.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)

Matt Pietrek article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Compiler forbids it becouse windows (exe loader in windows) forbid it.. I mean if i will generate exe with sections aligned say to 256 and fields set apropriately the windows will not run it

Why windows forbid it i dont know.. I fullt agree that it should be alowwed to have it smaller (i would like to heve it for example 64 or 16)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is any REAL technical reason why the alignment can't be zero (or at least some much smaller value than 512 - there may be issues with it being less than say 4, 8 or 16, as data alignment could end up being wrong if the compiler has produced code that relies on the whole section being aligned too small. But I also expect this feature was introduced to solve some specific use-case, and in most cases, it's not necessary to use this option. I can say that I've never used it myself.

However, using 4096 would make a lot of sense, because it means that a section is not sharing a page with another section.

I also suspect that /filealign:0 means "default alignment".

I would also heed the comment:

> most developers do not need to use this option

Comment: Note that filealign has nothing to do with in-memory layout, it has to do with in-file layout. It rarely has value other than 512. Minimum align for in-memory layout is 4k for the reasons you outline.